# How can I mock a third-party nodejs module function using jest with TypeScript?

Tags: typescript, npm, mocking, jestjs

I am trying to mock a function in a third-party node module, specifically the `fs.readFileSync()` function, using jest. There are quite a few examples out there but I haven't found one which uses TypeScript. I have a simple, hopefully minimal, example at [github](https://github.com/asmallfurrywombat/jest_typescript_mock_test). This is probably a simple issue for someone familiar with jest.

Comment: Yes, Mr Cantarela, typescript is Microsoft's take on javascript. I did start out with FB's Flow, but found that typescript combined with vscode was quite good so it seemed worthwhile pursuing a combination of typescript/jest(js) :).

Answer (score 19, accepted):

Here are a few different ways of mocking something like `fs.readFileSync()`:

**Mock the function**

To mock a function use [`jest.spyOn()`](https://jestjs.io/docs/en/jest-object#jestspyonobject-methodname) in combination with functions like [`mockImplementation()`](https://jestjs.io/docs/en/mock-function-api#mockfnmockimplementationfn):

```ts
import { returnNameInJsonFile } from './index';
import * as fs from 'fs';

describe('index', () => {

  it('returnNameInJsonFile', () => {
    const mock = jest.spyOn(fs, 'readFileSync');  // spy on fs.readFileSync()
    mock.mockImplementation(() => JSON.stringify({ name: 'myname' }));  // replace the implementation

    const name: string = returnNameInJsonFile('test.json');
    expect(name).toBe('myname');

    mock.mockRestore();  // restore fs.readFileSync()
  });

});
```

---

**Mock the module using a factory**

Pass a [module factory to `jest.mock()`](https://jestjs.io/docs/en/jest-object#jestmockmodulename-factory-options):

```ts
import { returnNameInJsonFile } from './index';

jest.mock('fs', () => {
  const MOCK_FILE_INFO = { 'test.json': JSON.stringify({ name: 'myname' }) };
  return {
    readFileSync: (fpath, opts) => {
      if (fpath in MOCK_FILE_INFO) {
        return MOCK_FILE_INFO[fpath]
      }
      throw 'unexpected fpath'
    }
  }
});

describe('index', () => {
  it('returnNameInJsonFile', () => {
    const name: string = returnNameInJsonFile('test.json');
    expect(name).toBe('myname'); // 1.0.0 is installed and 2.0.0 is available
  });
});
```

---

**Mock the module automatically**

Create [a mock for the module](https://jestjs.io/docs/en/manual-mocks).

`Jest` will use the mock automatically unless it is a core Node module (like `fs`) in which case [calling `jest.mock()` is required](https://jestjs.io/docs/en/manual-mocks#mocking-node-modules).

__mocks__/fs.ts:

```ts
const fs = jest.genMockFromModule('fs');

let mockFiles: object = {};

function __setMockFiles (newMockFiles: object) {
  mockFiles = newMockFiles;
}

function readFileSync(filePath: string) {
  return mockFiles[filePath] || '';
}

// If anyone knows how to avoid the type assertion feel free to edit this answer
(fs as any).__setMockFiles = __setMockFiles;
(fs as any).readFileSync = readFileSync;

module.exports = fs;
```

index.test.ts:

```ts
import { returnNameInJsonFile } from './index';

jest.mock('fs');  // Required since fs is a core Node module

describe('index', () => {

  const MOCK_FILE_INFO = { 'test.json': JSON.stringify({ name: 'myname' }) };

  beforeEach(() => {
    require('fs').__setMockFiles(MOCK_FILE_INFO);
  });

  it('returnNameInJsonFile', () => {
    const name: string = returnNameInJsonFile('test.json');
    expect(name).toBe('myname'); // 1.0.0 is installed and 2.0.0 is available
  });
});
```

Comment: this works for now - thanks! I've updated [the github example](https://github.com/asmallfurrywombat/jest_typescript_mock_test)

Comment: @nicky88 sounds like you wanted to mock the entire module, I updated my answer with a couple of ways of doing that

Comment: much appreciated, @brian-lives-outdoors .. I suspect it may be of use to others as well.

Comment: @brian-lives-outdoors this solution _should_ work, but I'm getting an error back from Typescript that is frustrating to fix.

`Property '__setMockFiles' does not exist on type 'typeof import("fs")'`

I guess I'd need to "trick" TS into realizing there is a function on the 'fs' library (when mocked).

And optionally (when using require inline): `TypeError: require(...).__setMockFiles is not a function`